# Creating element sets via python for Abaqus using geometry

Tags: python, set, element, abaqus

I am trying to create *element sets* in Abaqus via a python script.
The code below is what I am using for that. The element set is created when I run my script, but abaqus always indicates the set with an exclamation mark and wants me to **"Reselect the geometry for the set"**.
What do I need to change in my code to get rid of that error.

I was also thinking of just using the sequenceFromLabels method to create my element sets, but the elements created by abaqus (even tho I use a structured mesh) are kinda mixed up because its not a simple geometry so I don't see a good way to create them by using labels. Anyways I am open to any idea on how to use an other method to create the element sets.

```
    elements = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Kesselgeometrie_Vollkessel'].elements.getByBoundingBox(0, 0, 0, 1, 1,1) 
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Kesselgeometrie_Vollkessel'].Set(elements=elements, name='Test2')
```

Thanks for any advice!
Best regards cluue

Answer (score 0):

Dumbest question on stack overflow ever asked I feel like. Anyways the answer to my question is to make the box big enough so that there are actually elements inside the box.

Comment: Don't worry, it also occurred to me ;)

Comment: I appreciate you posting it, I didn't know that was a method in Abaqus and its helped me!